# downloading multiple high resolution images leading the app to crash

Tags: objective-c, imagedownload

I'm downloading high-resolution images in a table view, for each cell, there is a large image.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet AsyncImageView *menuItemLogo;
.
.
.
- (void)setCellWithImage:(NSString *)imageURL
{
    if (imageURL && [imageURL length]) {
        self.menuItemLogo.imageUrl = imageURL;
        [self.menuItemLogo startImageLoad];
    }
    else {
        self.menuItemLogo.image = [Application placeholderImage];
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_launcher"];
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function to fill the cells with the imageURL received from the backend. and display it in the  "menuItemLogo"
after several seconds, the app is crashing and I'm receiving memory warning.
any help? thanks.

Comment: Can you show logged error and `startImageLoad` method?

Comment: its a locked library, i cant access the startImageLoad method

Comment: It's hard to say what is the reason for your problem if we can't know how  `startImageLoad` method is implemented. In my opinion, you can fix it by using another library like SDWebImage.

Comment: i tried the new library, the app is still crashing on a real device, while it works normally on the simulator

Comment: Do you know which lines made it crash?

Comment: im not getting any error, just a message on xcode telling me :Restore the connection to “Administrator’s iPad” and run “app name” again, or if “app name” is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > app name.

Comment: what is the size of the image?

Comment: the size of the picture = 300

Answer (score 0):

This is best library for loading image from URL. you can check it.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

This library give many option you can also set place holder.

Comment: i tried the new library, the app is still crashing on a real device, while it works normally on the simulator

Comment: is it possible to provide a some image URL? like a response of the server. it is better if you provide the Request URL.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying very large image will cause memory issues in limited memory environments. You can reference Apple example [Large Image Downsizing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: and how can i do it? is there any example?

Comment: You can download the example code at the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/LargeImageDownsizing.zip) mentioned above. The example code write by Apple